# km2 or sqkm - which is more correct?

Tags: labeling, annotation, area

What is more correct, km2 or sqkm?

I'd prefer to use km with a superscript 2, but it's not always possible to format text that way so I was just wondering if there is a convention that should be used when you can't use superscript formatting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I generally use the character `²` or U+00B2. So it is km², without requiring any special formatting.

If you have a MS Windows keyboard, type the sequence: Alt+0178

Other platforms have different ways of typing this character. You can also copy/paste the Unicode character. More info: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm

Comment: Alt+0178 - that's what I needed, thanks Mike